# Intercept incoming URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, redirect

When a user navigates to my site with a qualified URL (e.g. mysite.com/abc.html) I want to call a javascript function first before showing any pages.  I need that because my site is driven by ajax.

I have a function that’s called when the page is first loaded:

```
<body onload="FirstJSFunction(150);”>
```

That function will intercept the URL and do what I want, but only if the qualified URL is mysite.com/index.html.  Any other valid URL within the site will bypass the javascript function and load the requested page.  That’s not what I want.

Here is how FirstJSFunction handles it:

```
<script>
function FirstJSFunction(type) {
  var gurl = GetURL();
  length = gurl.length;
  console.log("SFR URL " + length);
  var pos = gurl.lastIndexOf("/");
  console.log ("SFR_LastFwdSlash " + pos);
  if (length > pos) {
  var sub1 = gurl.substr(pos, length);
  console.log ("SFR_Sub1 " + sub1);
  sub2 = sub1.substr(1, 5);
  console.log ("SFR_Sub2 " + sub2);         
  if (sub2 == "index") {
    ShowAjax(3);
    return true; }
  if (sub2 != "index") {
    ShowAjax(3);
    return true; }
}
</script>

<script>
function GetURL() {
  var loc_href = location.href;
  console.log ("URL " + loc_href);
  var length = loc_href.length;
  console.log ("Length " + length);
  var pos = loc_href.lastIndexOf("/");
  console.log ("LastFwdSlash " + pos);
  var pos2 = loc_href.indexOf("/");
  console.log ("FwdSlash " + pos2);
  if (length > pos) {
  var substr = loc_href.substr(pos, length);
  console.log ("Substring " + substr);
  return substr;  }
}
</script>
```

So my question is:  when the user navigates to my site with any URL other than mysite.com or mysite.com/index.html – for example mysite.com/abc.html – why doesn’t the code above work to intercept the URL and call the javascript function, as happens if the URL is index.html.

Just to clarify, I only want to intercept the first incoming URL.  I am not looking to intercept any URL the user enters into the address bar after they have arrived at my site.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Well is that code *on* all of those other pages? It sounds like what you actually want is a SPA.

Comment: You need to configure server to redirect to main page. You also seem to have a bit of misunderstanding how pages sent from server work and where the javascript in them gets run

Comment: Depends what the site is built on. Is there a framework? You need to check the docs to find out what part of the framework is actually hit first when someone makes their first request.

Comment: I don't want to redirect to the main page, I want to call an ajax function.

Comment: If you are using ajax call to load another page, the function will not be triggered again. So, you should trigger this function in your ajax call before displaying a new page

Comment: To @jonrsharpe -- the code is not on the other pages, which may be the issue.  I'll test that now .

Comment: That ajax is called from browser...after a page gets sent from server

Comment: If it's an SPA there *is* only one page. Please give a [mcve], the description so far is baffling.

Comment: I corrected that in my last comment.  This is not technically an SPA.  I will put the code on another page and try that.  It sounds like the right answer.

Comment: If there are other pages that don't have the code on, it's unclear why you expected it might run when they loaded. It working on the page it was on but not on the ones it wasn't seems like a giveaway!

Comment: Before you start copying that script to every HTML document, please use an external script instead. (although all of this seems extremely fishy to me, like a huge xy problem)

Comment: I am using an external .js file reference on each page, not the entire code.

Comment: My problem right now is I want the js function to execute before the page content shows.  I'm working on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about everything you explained, so making some assumptions here.

But if that JS code is only on index.html, then it will never run for any other page. For that you would need to include it in every page.
Only the server is able to "see" all the pages accessed by your users.

Comment: Based on the comment above by @jonsharpe I think that is the issue.  I'm testing that now.